# WPF button template in app.xaml how to set the text in MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a glass button in the app.xaml file (code bottom of this post). I have a few buttons that reference this template in the mainwindox.xaml. What I do not know how to do is set the text that the button displays from within the MainWindow. The first section of code below is an example of one of the buttons. Somewhere I need to add some code so the button has the text 'Correlation' on it.

**Main Window code below**

```
 <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource buttBasicTemplateReport}" Command="{Binding CommandButtReportsCorrel}" Height="50" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

**App.xaml Code below**

```
         <!-- Glass Button empty template Report -->
    <Style x:Key="buttBasicTemplateReport" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" 
                              CornerRadius="15,15,15,15" 
                              BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" 
                              Background="#AA000000"  
                              BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF"
                              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1.7*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="23,23,0,0">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#08FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#88FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                            Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="recGlow"  Style="{StaticResource recSecurity}"
                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource txtSecurity}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="recGlow" Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ButtonBorder">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

`Button` is a `ContentControl`. As I see, you have a `ContentPresenter` in your `Template`. So, you can just add `Content` attribute to your `Button` or add `Contnet` element.

By attribute:

```
<Button Content="Correlation"/>
```

By element:

```
<Button>Correlation</Button>
```

Comment: When I add the Content="Correlation" the button shows "Correlati" for some reason the text is not centred. It appears as the text reaches the middle of the button the rest of the text is not visible

Comment: Because you have explicitly set the `Width="120"` for your `Button` which is don't enough to fit that text.

Comment: Yes of course your right I can now see all the text. However the text appears centred in the left hand side of the button, not centred in the button as a whole

Answer (score 0):

When you make custom buttons you need to use ContentControl and Triggers if you want onClick effects.
Also to answer your question from the comentar, when you make custom buttons you need to Bind the margin to padding property to center your button content.

You can see this link:

[WPF: Why shouldn't I use {TemplateBinding Margin} in ControlTemplate - is Margin meant only for element's containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006872/wpf-why-shouldnt-i-use-templatebinding-margin-in-controltemplate-is-margin)

You can see this also:

http://sshumakov.com/2013/02/19/how-to-bind-to-control-properties-from-controltemplate/