# Vertically align a WPF RadioButton bullet and stretch its contents

Tags: wpf, radio-button, alignment

I want to use a grid, stretched across the entire available area, as the content for a RadioButton, and I want the RadioButton's bullet to be vertically aligned.

Getting the grid to stretch across the entire area is easy enough, I just set the HorizontalContentAlignment property on the RadioButton:

```
<RadioButton HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>Foo</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">The quick brown fox</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</RadioButton>
```

And following Simon Weaver's answer to this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533753/how-do-i-make-a-radiobuttons-bullet-align-top#7815808), I can vertically align the radio button's bullet relatively easily:

```
<RadioButton HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock>Foo</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">The quick brown fox</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```

The trouble is, having done that, the content no longer stretches.
[image: one or the other]

How can I get a vertically aligned bullet **and** a stretching grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextBlock is being stretched properly, but the grid inside it is not. Presumably that's just the way TextBlock works.

The following is a bit hacky, but it works:

```
<RadioButton HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Name="Text" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=Text, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for the visual effect.  You didn't list any functional requirements so i'm not sure if it will work for you without some event mapping or not.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content=""/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Foo</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">The quick brown fox</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]